# Specifying "noproxy" for node.js client request

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, curl, proxy

My OS has a system-wide proxy set. I believe the following call is trying to go through that proxy:

```
var client = http.createClient(8124, '127.0.0.1'); // couchdb
var request_db = client.request('GET', '/status');
```

Similar to curl's `--noproxy 127.0.0.1`, how would I set that kind of functionality in node.js calls?

Comment: What made you think it goes through the proxy? Have you some trace/logs to show?

Comment: what maksymko said.  Are you sure this is going through a proxy?  To access a proxy, you have to connect to a specific server/host.  But since you're connecting directly to the host/port of your server, I doubt a proxy is involved.

Try disabling the proxy and see what happens.  I'm betting it still works.

Comment: I can't answer this, but make sure to stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions! Make sure to report back with your findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same value for the proxy path and the host:

```
var options = {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 8124,
  path: "http://127.0.0.1/status",
  headers: {
    Host: "127.0.0.1"
  }
};
http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```